# Oracle PL/SQL function with input parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I am beginner in PL/SQL. I created FUNCTION which reverses string and which changes every 3rd char in a string. I created this function with some help. And now I need to remove this `'abcdeFgh'` and set function so i have input parameter. How can I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RIS.tmp_tzk1_f_preslozi_string
RETURN string
IS 
str VARCHAR2(20) := 'abcdeFgh';
znak CHAR := '';
len NUMBER;
brojac_svako_trece INTEGER := 0;
str1 VARCHAR(20) := '';
BEGIN
    len := LENGTH(str);
    FOR i IN REVERSE 1..len
    LOOP
        brojac_svako_trece := brojac_svako_trece +1;
        znak := SUBSTR (str, i, 1);
        IF MOD(brojac_svako_trece,3) = 0 THEN
            brojac_svako_trece := 0;
            IF ASCII(znak)<97 THEN
                znak := LOWER(znak);
            ELSE 
                znak := UPPER(znak);
            END IF;
        END IF;
        str1 := str1 || znak;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN str1;
  dbms_output.put_line(str1);
END;

DECLARE
   RetVal   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
   RetVal := RIS.TMP_TZK1_F_PRESLOZI_STRING;
   dbms_output.put_line(RetVal);
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work you were so close.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_tzk1_f_preslozi_string (str IN VARCHAR)
RETURN string
IS 
    znak CHAR := '';
    len NUMBER;
    brojac_svako_trece INTEGER := 0;
    str1 VARCHAR(20) := '';

BEGIN
    len := LENGTH(str);
    FOR i IN REVERSE 1..len
    LOOP
        brojac_svako_trece := brojac_svako_trece +1;
        znak := SUBSTR (str, i, 1);
        IF MOD(brojac_svako_trece,3) = 0 THEN
            brojac_svako_trece := 0;
            IF ASCII(znak)<97 THEN
                znak := LOWER(znak);
            ELSE 
                znak := UPPER(znak);
            END IF;
        END IF;
        str1 := str1 || znak;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN str1;
END;

DECLARE
   RetVal   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN

   RetVal := TMP_TZK1_F_PRESLOZI_STRING('DobarDan');

   dbms_output.put_line(RetVal);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty simple actually:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RIS.tmp_tzk1_f_preslozi_string(
    str IN VARCHAR2 --> add input params here
) RETURN string
IS 
    znak CHAR := '';
    len NUMBER;
    brojac_svako_trece INTEGER := 0;
    str1 VARCHAR(20) := '';
BEGIN
    -- your code goes here
END;
```